# Projection of n-Simplex into k-Simplex

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization

I try to find properties of orthogonal projections such that a standard $n$-Simplex $S_n$ is projected into a $k$-Simplex $S_k (k\leq n)$. Literature provides work on "smallest projections" in this context.

If the projected object is a $k$-Simplex, then $n$-$k$ corners of $S_n$ have to lie inside $S_k$. This can be formalized with barycentric coordinates.

I reformulated it in order to express conditions on the underlying projection matrix and obtained a set of linear inequalities. Orthogonality can enter to eliminate some variables.

Are there alternative approaches or results?